# Is there a module for evaluating simple expressions?

Tags: python

Is there a module for evaluating simple expressions?

I don't want to use `eval` as it can execute dangerous code.

I tried ast.literal_eval, but it seems a bit too featureless.

```py
import ast
ast.literal_eval("1 > 0")
# ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Compare object at 0x7f075725d350>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ast.parse`

```
expr = ast.parse("1 > 0", mode='eval')

# Walk trough your expression and if you consider it not dangerous then eval.

print(ast.dump(expr, indent=4))

Expression(
    body=Compare(
        left=Constant(value=1),
        ops=[
            Gt()],
        comparators=[
            Constant(value=0)]))
```

Comment: Can I receive the evaluation results?

Comment: Yes. If you consider the expression is not dangerous then you can do `eval("1 > 0")`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely safe, but eval seems to fulfill my wishes.

```py
eval("1 > 0", {"__builtins__": {}}, {})
# True
```